# Sum of the Stirling numbers of the second kind multiplied by $k$ and falling factorials

Tags: co.combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I am looking for closed forms, or at least a good approximation for

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{k}(n)_kk$$

I know that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{k}(n)_k = n^n$$

I have the intuition that $f(n)$ is bounded above by $n^{n+1}$ and approaches $n^{n+1}$ for large $n$ but I am not entirely sure and don't know how to form a proof (or anti-proof).

Sorry if this question is too basic for math overflow, I wasn't sure if it belonged here or elsewhere.

Comment: Calculate the first few terms and then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I believe that the consensus is generally to [avoid edits that solely introduce LaTeX in titles](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/591/editing-titles-to-include-mathfraklatex-math).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that $(x)_k - (x-1)_k = k (x-1)_{k-1}$.   So applying the linear operator $f \mapsto xf(x) - xf(x-1)$, to the identity  $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{k}(x)_k = x^n $$ we get that  $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{k} k (x)_k = x^{n+1} - x(x-1)^n.$$

**Edit:** In retrospect, there is also a enumerative proof.  The left hand side counts the set of functions from $[n] \to [x]$ together with a choice of point in the image.  The right hand counts the set  offunctions from $[n] \sqcup * \to [x]$ minus the set of functions such that the image of $*$ and $[n]$ are disjoint.